# My Facebook was disabled by mistake, how long does it take to get it back?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-messenger, facebook-timeline, facebook-privacy

On November 20th I was first told you send a photo of me for security and it was being reviewed.

Now on December 24th my account was disabled when I had to wait a whole month to wait so I sent a photo of my birth certificate to "My personal account was disabled" and i'm still waiting for my account to be back on because my birth certificate shows my birth date and name.

Is anybody else having this problem?? I heard a lot of people are having this problem.

Comment: Not a problem.  I realize you are looking for help with this specific issue, but it might be hard for someone else to know what's going on in the recesses of Facebook.  We're not really affiliated with any particular web application, so we have no way of knowing what their internal policies are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Help Centre](https://www.facebook.com/help/103873106370583/?ref=u2u):

> Facebook [disable accounts](https://www.facebook.com/help/185747581553788/) that don't follow the [Facebook Terms](https://www.facebook.com/terms). Some examples include:
>
> - Posting content that doesn't follow the Facebook Terms
> - Using a fake name
> - Impersonating someone
> - Continuing behavior that's not allowed on Facebook by violating our Community Standards
> - Contacting other people for the purpose of harassment, advertising, promoting, dating or other conduct that's not allowed
>
> If you think your account was disabled by mistake, please [submit an appeal](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/260749603972907).

Comment: I did "My personal account was disabled" and sent a photo of my birth certificate but still waiting.